# Node.js : Pass token in consul kv get

Tags: node.js, acl, consul

I am using consul to get some configurations in my Node.js project.

I was able to access the consul key-value pairs with the code given below.

```
import consul from 'consul';
(new consul()).kv.get('config', (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("result", result);
});
```

(Using npm "consul")

Now, I have protected consul with ACL and have created 3 tokens:
master_token, a token with write access and a token with read access

As the consul is now ACL protected, the code mentioned above shows me "permission denied"
how can I pass this token in the kv.get method to authenticate my request ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing the consul client you can use the `defaults` option to define a token which should be sent with every query.

```js
import consul from 'consul';

var defaultRequestOptions = {
    token: '43d8f1cb-3c73-44a2-a1d6-c4fe1b9b1537'
};

(new consul({defaults: defaultRequestOptions})).kv.get('config', (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("result", result);
});
```

See [Common Method Call Options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consul#common-method-call-options) for a full list of available default options.